# trigger lightbox2 with javascript

Tags: lightbox2

How can I trigger [lightbox2](/questions/tagged/lightbox2) with javascript on page load?

Comment: Show some code what you have tried before.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than i thought. I triggered a click with jQuery and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.myLightbox').trigger('click');
   });
</script>
```